# IMB Plex font is not changing color when switched from light to dark mode in NextJs 13

Tags: fonts, next.js13

I am using IBM Plex Serif for my heading elements. The font is locally stored in my NextJs 13 project. And, I am using ShadCn for theming. However, when I change the theme from light mode to a dark mode, the font color for all my fonts change except for my H1, H2, ... H6 (heading) fonts.

Here's how my RootLayout.tsx file looks like:

```js
import localFont from "next/font/local";

const fontHeading = localFont({
  src: "../assets/fonts/IBMPlexSerif-Bold.ttf",
  variable: "--font-heading",
  display: "swap",
});

interface RootLayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <head />
        <body
          className={cn(
            "min-h-screen bg-background font-sans antialiased",
            fontSans.variable,
            fontMono.variable,
            fontHeading.variable
          )}
        >
          <ThemeProvider
            attribute="class"
            defaultTheme="light"
            enableSystem
            disableTransitionOnChange
            storageKey="copilot-theme"
          >
            {children}
            <TailwindIndicator />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  );
}
```

I Googled for a while, but didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Can you please, provide the code for H1, H2, H6 (heading) tags ?
(edit the above question & add the code)

Comment: I actually found a different way to fix the issue. I simply added dark:text-white tailwind CSS property. However, it requires me to add this className everytime I use headings... 
PS. I am just learning how to code, so...

Answer (score 0):

With respective to the above comment,

Instead of applying `dark:text-white`, try applying `text-foreground` to your heading tags.

If `globals.css` has foreground color, then Tailwind will apply foreground color mentioned inside dark/light theme with respect to dark mode/ light mode.

If `globals.css` file has `.dark` class in it, then it will work.

**Explanation :**

In light mode text-foreground = color inside .root[--foreground]

In dark mode text-foreground = color inside .dark[--foreground]

if you look inside `tailwind.config.js` :

under theme you will find :

```
background: "hsl(var(--background))",
foreground: "hsl(var(--foreground))",
```

`globals.css` might look this (i have excluded extra code) :

```
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%;
    --foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
    .
    .
    .
  }
 
  .dark {
    --background: 20 14.3% 4.1%;
    --foreground: 0 0% 95%;
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

**Please Read** : https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/theming (Scroll down to **Convention Section**)

> If possible please update this question with your tailwind.config.js, globals.css & Heading tags code.
> This help in giving more accurate answer.